# Cannot get keychain password via SSH

Tags: macos, keychain, macos-big-sur

On a Mac (Big Sur) machine, I can easily get a password from the keychain via the command line:
`security find-generic-password -l Foo -w`

But, if I ssh into that same machine, the exact same command returns nothing.

Any ideas why that would be happening?

Comment: You might get more help at [askdifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). The keychain is probably locked when you get in via ssh. You can unlock it with the `security unlock-keychain` command.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Holt's response helped me.

Indeed the remote keychain was locked and can be unlocked with `security unlock-keychain`.  If you are interacting via the command line perhaps using a script you can test for whether the **default** keychain is unlocked with `show-keychain-info` which returns a non-zero value when locked.

In bash selectively prompt to unlock the keychain (with squashing of the redundant text output of show-keychain-info to stderr):

```
if ! $(security show-keychain-info 2> /dev/null); then
    security unlock-keychain;
fi
```